# String Trimmer and trimmed Input routine

Tags: c++

As I thought about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523476/how-to-skip-a-field-without-entering-value-in-c) on SO, I realized that I wanted to implement either a string trimmer or a trimmed string inputter.

This is what I came up with, but I have a nagging feeling I could have done better.

Would you critique this, please?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

template <typename Ch, typename Tr, typename Alloc>
void
trim(std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, Alloc>& str, const std::locale& loc)
{
  // (b,e)=ltrim(str)
  typename std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, Alloc>::const_iterator b = str.begin();
  typename std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, Alloc>::const_iterator e = str.end();
  while( b != e && std::isspace(*b, loc) )
    b++;

  // (b,e)=rtrim(b,e)
  // Query: this loop looks u-g-l-y. Can it be less ugly?
  while( b != e ) {
    e--;
    if(!std::isspace(*e, loc)) {
      e++;
      break;
    }
  }

  // str=(b,e)
  // Query: this string self-assigns (sort of). Is this UB?
  str.assign(b, e);
}

template <typename Ch, typename Tr, typename Alloc>
std::basic_istream<Ch,Tr>&
getTrimmedLine(std::basic_istream<Ch,Tr>& is,
  std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, Alloc>& str)
{

  // Get raw data from input
  std::getline(is, str);

  // And trim it
  trim(str, is.getloc());

  return is;
}

#define TEST
#ifdef TEST
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t countof( T (& a)[N] ) { return N; }

int main () {
  const char * const inputs[] = {
    "simple", " front", "back ", " both ",
    "  front2", "back2  ", "  both2  ",
    "\n", "", "\n\n\n",
    "  \n", "  ", "  \n\n\n"
  };
  const char * const outputs[] = {
    "simple", "front", "back", "both",
    "front2", "back2", "both2",
    "", "", "",
    "", "", ""
  };

  assert(countof(inputs) == countof(outputs));

  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < countof(inputs); i++) {
    std::istringstream is(inputs[i]);
    std::string result;
    getTrimmedLine(is, result);
    assert(result == outputs[i]);
  }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- Would you lose anything if `trim` took a single template parameter that would accept the type of the string?  You're not doing anything with the individual parameters, after all.
- I don't think the second loop is particularly ugly.  You could use `operator-` first and then only decrement if it's not a space, but I don't think that's particularly useful.
- Honestly don't know, about the undefined behaviour, you should ask on StackOverflow (I'm fairly certain that's on-topic there).
- I think you should check that `std::getline` left the stream in a good state before applying `trim`.  You may also want to provide the possibility to pass extra parameters to `std::getline`.
- `countof` should have the signature `std::size_t countof( T const (& a)[N] )`.

Answer (score 2):

```
typename std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, Alloc>::const_iterator e = str.end();
...

// Query: this loop looks u-g-l-y. Can it be less ugly?
  while( b != e ) {
    e--;
    if(!std::isspace(*e, loc)) {
      e++;
      break;
    }
  }
```

This looks weird and tends to go UB.

1) e = str.end();

2) e--; /* it's better to use --e in this case */ you move one more far position after end()!!!

3) std::isspace(***e**, loc) <--- UB, accessing the memory that haven't been allocated

If you need to find the first and the last spaces in the string, use this:

```
b = find_if(str.begin(),  str.end(),  isspace_predicate);
e = find_if(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), isspace_predicate);
```